# I got this error Syntax error, malformed JSON

Tags: php, json, api

Im integrating Lightspeed API to my website like POS system. I currently getting the value file_get_contents(), but when Im trying to load it array I gives my the error 4 of json_last_error().

Here is my codes:

```
$maps_url = "http://cloud-docs.merchantos.com/API/Account/797/Item/?itemID=1";

$maps_json = file_get_contents($maps_url);  
//print_r($maps_json);

$maps_array = json_decode(stripslashes($maps_json), true);
echo $data = $maps_array['Item']['systemSku'];


    switch (json_last_error()) {
case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
    echo ' - No errors';
    break;
case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
    echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
    echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
    echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
    echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
    echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
default:
    echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
    }

json_last_error();
```

Comment: Well, you're receiving XML. So naturally the JSON decoder will bark.

Comment: this line are not display it must display systemSKU, echo $data = $maps_array['Item']['systemSku'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me rephrase it then:

- The shown URL does **not** retrieve *JSON*.
- It pulls *XML*.
- Therefore [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) fails.
- Hence there's no usable data in `$maps_url`.
- Which is also why `['Item']['systemSku']` **won't work**.
- (And [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes) would have made no sense in there anyway).

So, investigate the API you're using. Figure out if there is a JSON variant available. Else throw away your code, and instead use a XML traversal frontend, such as [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/SimpleXML).

Answer (score 0):

As mario has said, $maps_url receives XML.

Check out [xml_parse_into_struct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php) for help with XML to array conversion.

Comment: Please add some explanation.